Does an array of Peltier module need a diode between each module?
I have a bunch of Peltier module that I wish to connect in series/parallel and use them as a thermopile generator. However I was wondering if its necessary to attach a diode between each module (see image) to prevent one thermopile module from "powering" the adjacent module. Is this a valid concern? or can I directly connect the modules together w/o diodes?

Are all Peltier modules always at the same temperatures?

Do all the Peltier modules have the identical number of elements?

@KevinWhite, the modules temperature difference would stay within 1-2°C relative to each other.

@SpehroPefhany, the modules will have identical number of elements
